# Where are my iPhone Messages notifications?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, messages

Recently I've noticed that I have no notifications (no badge, no bubbles) for SMS/iMessage in my iPhone. I have the following settings:

- Notifications: allow, show in notification centre, sounds - note, badge app icon, show on lock screen;
- Messages: iMessage, text message forwarding - my iPad, my MacBook - all off, send and receive - my phone and email;
- Do not disturb - off.

For me this looks like a serious bug (in 9.3.5?) or a security issue, but since I've checked text message forwarding I don't know how it could be.

What else to check or how to fix this?

Comment: If you have Messages set up on another device (like your iPad or MacBook) and read messages there, notifications and the badge will disappear from all other devices as soon as it's read. Did you try disabling notifications, doing a hard reset (Home + Sleep until the Apple logo appears) then re-enabling them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often a hard reset of the device will fix problems. Powering off and back on doesn't do the same thing as it does for a computer - it's more akin to hibernate mode in that its drawing no power, but nothing (RAM etc) is cleared.

To do a hard reset, on iPhone 6s and below, press and hold Sleep and Home until the Apple logo appears. On iPhone 7 and higher, press and hold Volume Down and Home.